# Why does my C# variable return null in Jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery

I have initiated the variables and declared them

```
protected string Image1;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string Image1 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt1"];
    }
}
```

I have called the variables from jquery properly and when I test the link I get nothing

```
 $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function () {
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    href: '<%=Image1%>',/*returns '' instead of 'path/image.jpg'*/
                    title: 'My title'
                }
            ], {
                helpers: {
                    thumbs: {
                        width: 75,
                        height: 50
                    }
                }
            });
```

I figured out that the `<%=Image1%>` that I placed inside the javascript was returning null because when I removed all values from the `href` attribute I got the same error.

```
href:'' /*causes the jquery not to fire when the link is clicked*/
```

Finally, I tested to see if the `Request.QueryString` was returning null so I placed the value of `image1` in a label

```
lblImage1.Text = Image1; //returns 'path/image.jpg'
```

And the path to the image posted in the label. Why is the same variable blank in jQuery? What am I missing?

Comment: You need ReSharper - it would warn you to the fact that you've hidden the protected Image1 by defining a new variable inside Page_Load.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you set value to local variable created in the scope of the *if* condition only.

Change the line to this and it will work:

```
Image1 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt1"];
```

Comment: Gets 7 up votes in the first minute of the answer, now 8... guess Shadow Wizard is gaming the rep system perhaps?

Comment: Gaming?  He gave the first answer and its a good one IMO, so I upvoted

Comment: Maybe I need to come by SO more often then... never seen a question up vote realtime like that in first 60 secs... carry on.

Comment: I know Jon Skeet and he is no Shadow Wizard ;)

Comment: Quite the interesting social dynamic I stumbled upon ... later all

Comment: Shadow Wizard uses Great Answer. It's super-effective! xD (sorry, couldn't help myself)

Comment: @Alxandr I was trying to think how I can improve it to justify all the rep but honestly, can't see any way lol!

Answer (score 2):

You have two variables named "Image1". One of them will (according to the code you wrote) never be set to anything (and it's the one that's printed).

```
protected string Image1;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string Image1 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt1"]; // introduces a new variable named Image1
        // this.Image1 and Image1 are not the same variables
    }
    // local instance of Image1 is no more. (out of scope)
}
```

Try this instead

```
protected string Image1;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Image1 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt1"];
    }
}
```

Notice the lack of `string`. By prepending a variable by it's type, you create a new local instance of that variable there, in that scope.

Comment: Thanks sooo much for the explanation. I should have known this i stared at it for an hour. I wish I could mark 2 as answer Shadow Wizard beat you to the punch but you provided an excellent explaination!